# Abel's theorem infinite case

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, divergent-series

I would like to prove the second remark in the Wikipedia article of Abel's theorem:

Let $a_k $ be real numbers. If $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k = +\infty $ then $$\lim_{z\to 1^-} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z^k =+\infty, $$
provided that the radius of convergence of the series is $1$.

I tried to use the same ideas as in the usual case where $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k<\infty$ but without success.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using summation by parts with $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k$,

$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k = S_nx^n + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}S_k(x^k - x^{k+1}) = S_nx^n + (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}S_kx^k $$

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = \infty$, for any $M > 0$ there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $S_n > M$ for all $n \geqslant N$.

Hence, for $n > N$ we have 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k > Mx^n + (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}S_kx^k + (1-x)M\sum_{k=N}^{n-1}x^k \\ = Mx^n + (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}S_kx^k + (1-x)M\frac{x^N -x^{n}}{1-x} \\=  Mx^n + (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}S_kx^k + M(x^N -x^{n})  $$

For $0 < x < 1$, the series on the LHS converges and $x^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Thus,

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k \geqslant  (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}S_kx^k + Mx^N. $$

From here you should be able to finish by showing that for any $M > 0$,

$$\lim_{x \to 1-}\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k \geqslant M   $$

Comment: Oh, I thought the $a_k $ were complex and $\sum a_k =\infty $ meant $|\sum a_k |\to + \infty $. Is the result still true in that case?